# Retrieving a string without the quotes using Unity's SimpleJSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am using the SimpleJSON script from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

```
JSONNode root = JSON.Parse ("{ \"Name\" : \"Joe\"}");
Debug.Log (root ["Name"].ToString().Length);
```

This returns `5` rather than `3`. This is because `root ["Name"]` is returning a string that is literally `"Joe"` (including the quotes, so that's 5 characters).

But that's not really what I wanted - I placed quotes in there because it is the only way the parser would work.

Of course I could simply remove the quotes manually by taking out a substring, but I have the feeling this is not how it is supposed to be going. So my question is: how can I retrieve the string `Joe` without the quotes using this script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `JSONNode` class is abstract; the `JSONData` class `ToString()` method inserts quotes. See:

```
public override string ToString ()
{
    return "\"" + Escape (m_Data) + "\"";
}
```

Try using the `Value` property instead:

```
JSONData root = JSON.Parse("{ \"Name\" : \"Joe\"}");
Debug.Log(root["Name"].Value.Length);
Debug.Log(root["Name"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Value property instead of calling ToString().

```
JSONNode root = JSON.Parse("{ \"Name\" : \"Joe\"}");
Console.WriteLine(root["Name"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(root["Name"].Value.Length);
```

Output:

```
Joe
3
```

Comment: What is the principal difference with previous answer?

Comment: No difference. Just a bit of inattentiveness.